# How to use 'classes' to customize compound components in Mui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to override the Mui styles by using the `classes` prop.

For example, I would like to override the [InputLabel](https://mui.com/api/input-label/#css) color of the [TextField](https://mui.com/api/text-field/) component.

I would like to use one definition of `makeStyles` that will set all css rules, starting at the root (TextField) and overriding whatever I want in the hierarchy (for example, the InputLabel when focused), when passing it to the component in the `classes` prop.

How is it done?

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import makeStyles from "@mui/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: "yellow",
    label: {
      color: "brown"
    }
  }
});
export default function Input() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField
      classes={classes}
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="Outlined"
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
}
```

**Answer**

```
     import * as React from "react";
     import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
     import makeStyles from "@mui/styles/makeStyles";
        
        const useStyles = makeStyles({
          root: {
             "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
              color: 'red',
              padding: "0.2rem"
               },
          },
        });
        export default function Input() {
          const classes = useStyles();
          return (
            <TextField 
             InputProps={{ classes }} 
             />;
           
          );
        }
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-theme-forked-ud5b5?file=/src/Input.tsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I found is to use the Mui v5 `sx` property.

(`makeStyles` is deprecated - https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#2-use-tss-react)

(`input` signifies the rule in https://mui.com/api/input-base/#css)

```
     import * as React from "react";
     import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";            
 
        export default function Input() {
          const classes = useStyles();
          return (
            <TextField
                 sx={{ 
                  "& input":
                   { padding: "0rem",color: "blue" } 
                    }}
            />
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `classes` prop in MUI gives you access to the CSS Rule Names for a component. When you're using this prop, check the API spec for that component. The CSS Rule Names are at the bottom of the page.

https://mui.com/api/text-field/#css

For this component, there is only 1 rule available (root), so this will (I think) have the same effect as just using `className`.

What you probably want to do is use the `InputProps` prop instead. The `Input` component has way more CSS Rules you can target: https://mui.com/api/input/#css

So, I think you probably want to do this:

```
    <TextField
      InputProps={{ classes }}
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="Outlined"
      variant="outlined"
    />
```

EDIT to help answer comment:

I don't think you need to target `InputBase`, as I believe you can target `input` instead. To target the `input` CSS Rule, just change the `root` key to `input`:

```
     import * as React from "react";
     import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
     import makeStyles from "@mui/styles/makeStyles";
        
        const useStyles = makeStyles({
          input: {
              color: 'red',
              padding: "0.2rem"
          },
        });
        export default function Input() {
          const classes = useStyles();
          return (
            <TextField 
             InputProps={{ classes }} 
             />;
           
          );
        }
```

The CSS rules in the docs are sensitive to the keys in the object you pass.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
Is there a way for me to avoid using `"& .MuiInputBase-input"` in the classes rules and use a css-rule (`inputbase`:{ padding:'0.2rem'}) name instead?  (for overriding deeply nested rules)

Comment: It does add the styles, but their selectors are not strong enough for them to override the Mui selectors. I need to add an "!important" for it to work. That's why I nested the input class under the root in my answer.

Comment: Looking further at this, it seems you can access the `InputBase` props from `Input`. `InputBase` takes a color prop! That's (probably) what's making it hard to select. https://mui.com/api/input-base/#props . Try: `InputProps={{color: "red"}}`

Comment: It still doesn't override the Mui classes. But I guess I need to move away from the deprecated `makeStyles` to the new`styled` method.